# Shortcode leads to white screen

Tags: shortcode

I have this code to show news in block. but when include this code in `functions.php` to call it in shortcode. It show me white page and not show me any error.

So where is my error?

For some reason, when I edit my `functions.php`, various pages turn white. For example, with this code:

```
function box_news_eight( $atts ) {
$code = '<div class="cf"></div>
<div class="box-home box-news-seven nb-eight">
    <div class="box-inner">
        <div  class="box-wrap">';
            $query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'cat' => 4, 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1, 'no_found_rows' => true, 'cache_results' => false ) );
            if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
                if ( $i_cont == 0 ) { $post_class = ' ws-post-first'; } else { $post_class = ' ws-post-sec'; }
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { $has_class =  ''; } else { $has_class =  ' no-thumb'; }
               $code .= ' <div class="post'.$post_class.$has_class.'" role="article" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">';              
                    $post_sidebars = '';
                    if ( $post_sidebars == 'sideNo' ) {
                        if ( function_exists("has_post_thumbnail") && has_post_thumbnail() ) : 
                            $code .= ' <div class="ws-thumbnail"><a href="'.get_the_permalink().'" rel="bookmark">
                                    .'get_the_post_thumbnail( 'bd-normal' )'.
                                </a></div>';
                            endif;
                        } else {
                                if ( function_exists("has_post_thumbnail") && has_post_thumbnail() ) :
                            $code .= '<div class="ws-thumbnail"><a href="'.get_the_permalink().'" rel="bookmark">';
                                        get_the_post_thumbnail( 'bd-large' );
                               $code .= '</a></div>';
                            endif; 
                        }
                    $code .= '<div class="ws-cap">
                        <div class="post-cats-bd">';
                            get_the_category( ' ' );
                        $code .= '</div>
                        <div class="ws-cap-inner">
                            <h3 itemprop="name" class="entry-title"><a itemprop="url" href="'.get_permalink( $post->ID ).'" rel="bookmark">'.get_the_title().'</a></h3>
                            <div class="post-date-bd">'.
                                get_time().'
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>';
                 $i_cont++; endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); wp_reset_query();
            $query = new WP_Query( array( 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1, 'offset'=>1, 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'cat' => 4, 'no_found_rows' => true, 'cache_results' => false ) );
            update_post_thumbnail_cache( $query );
            if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
                if ( $i_cont == 0 ) { $post_class = ' ws-post-first'; } else { $post_class = ' ws-post-sec'; }
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { $has_class =  ''; } else { $has_class =  ' no-thumb'; }


                if( $count % 3 == 1 ) { '<div class="row">'; }
                    $code .= '<div class="post'.$post_class.$has_class.'" role="article" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
                        <div class="ws-meta">
                            <h3 itemprop="name" class="entry-title"><a itemprop="url" href="<'.get_permalink( $post->ID ).' rel="bookmark">'.the_title().'</a></h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>';
                      if( $count % 3 == 0 ) { "</div>\n"; }
                      $count++;

                      $i_cont++; endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); wp_reset_query();
                  if ( $count % 3 != 1 )  "</div>";
        $code .= '</div>
    </div>
</div>';

return $code;
}
add_shortcode( 'box_news_eight', 'box_news_eight' );
```

Comment: [Enable Debugging, both `WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY` and `WP_DEBUG_LOG`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)

Comment: i enable it but not show any error`define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
error_reporting(0);`

Comment: You are also echoing output in your shortcode. You should not do that.

Comment: i dont echo any thing its must return output

Comment: You do. Please check your code. There are a couple of instances where you use `echo`. You return half the code and echo the other half

Comment: sorry , i see it, but i replace it and still show white page

Comment: Your code is a complete mess and really hard to read. Clean up your code, indent it properly, and you should find your issue

Comment: Also, you have never accepted any answer to your questions. Please revisit all your previous questions and accept all the answers that solved your issues. Please read [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: You are passing a string into `get_the_category();` while it is expecting an integer. (or nothing if you are getting the current category)

Answer (score 3):

As I already stated in comments, your code is a complete mess and very hard to read and to debug. This is most probably why you are having a hard time to sort your issues.

Apart from a few syntax errors, you had a couple of bugs in your code like undefined variables (like your counters, you should define a counter before using it), trying to output an array instead of string. Also, please stop the crap where check if a core function exists. It is totally a waste of time.

You should use one syntax, and do not use multiple different syntaxes. You are using the following

```
if( 'something' ) {
    if( 'something else' ) :
        // Do something
    endif;
}
```

Don't do that. It is confusing and a nightmare to debug as code editors in general do not support the `:` and `endif` syntax. Stick with curly brackets, they are easy to debug as all code editors support them. You should be using something like

```
if( 'something' ) {
    if( 'something else' ) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

You should work on your indentation. This is very important is your code's readability. Don't cram a lot of code like conditional statements in to one line. It is really hard to read and to debug should it fail

Instead of doing the following which is bad coding

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { $has_class =  ''; } else { $has_class =  ' no-thumb'; }
```

split the code up into multiple lines and indent it correctly. Your code should look something like this

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
    $has_class =  ''; 
} else { 
    $has_class =  ' no-thumb'; 
}
```

You can see that this is easier to read and to debug

`get_the_category()` returns an array, you are trying to output the complete array of categories as a string. This will just lead to the word `Array` being output to screen

If you want to display a category name, you can do something like this (*this will display the category name of the first category*)

```
$category = get_the_category();
var_dump( $category[0]->name );
```

If you are passing multiple parameters to `WP_Query`, don't pass it as one looooonnnnnnggggg line. Break it up into multiple lines which is easier to read

Instead of this

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'cat' => 4, 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1, 'no_found_rows' => true, 'cache_results' => false ) );
```

do the following which is easier to read

```
$args = array( 
    'posts_per_page'      => 1, 
    'cat'                 => 4, 
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1, 
    'no_found_rows'       => true, 
    'cache_results'       => false 
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I do not know why you need to run 2 queries here and if it is really necessary, but in any case, I have not touched that as I don't know what your intention is with this. Please compare my code with yours and see how my code compares to yours.

Here is your code cleaned up

```
add_shortcode( 'box_news_eight', 'box_news_eight' );
function box_news_eight() 
{
    $code = '<div class="cf"></div>
    <div class="box-home box-news-seven nb-eight">
        <div class="box-inner">
            <div  class="box-wrap">';

                $args = array( 
                    'posts_per_page'      => 1, 
                    'cat'                 => 4, 
                    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1, 
                    'no_found_rows'       => true, 
                    'cache_results'       => false 
                );
                $query = new WP_Query( $args );

                if ( $query->have_posts() ) { 
                    // Setup your counter
                    $i_cont = 0;

                    while ( $query->have_posts() ) { 
                        $query->the_post();

                        if ( $i_cont == 0 ) { 
                            $post_class = ' ws-post-first'; 
                        } else { 
                            $post_class = ' ws-post-sec'; 
                        }

                        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
                            $has_class =  ''; 
                        } else { 
                            $has_class =  ' no-thumb'; 
                        }
                        $code .= '<div class="post'.$post_class.$has_class.'" role="article" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">';

                        $post_sidebars = '';
                        if ( $post_sidebars == 'sideNo' ) {

                            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
                                $code .= '<div class="ws-thumbnail">
                                            <a href="'.get_the_permalink().'" rel="bookmark">'
                                                . get_the_post_thumbnail( 'bd-normal' ) .
                                            '</a>
                                        </div>';
                            }

                        } else {

                            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                                $code .= '<div class="ws-thumbnail">
                                            <a href="'.get_the_permalink().'" rel="bookmark">'
                                                . get_the_post_thumbnail( 'bd-large' ) .
                                            '</a>
                                        </div>';
                            } 

                        }
                        $category = get_the_category();
                        $code .= '<div class="ws-cap">
                                    <div class="post-cats-bd">'
                                        . $category[0]->name .
                                    '</div>
                                    <div class="ws-cap-inner">
                                        <h3 itemprop="name" class="entry-title"><a itemprop="url" href="' . get_permalink( $post->ID ) . '" rel="bookmark">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h3>
                                        <div class="post-date-bd">'
                                            . get_the_time() .
                                        '</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>';

                        $i_cont++; 
                    }
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                }

                $args_2 = array( 
                    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1, 
                    'offset'              => 1, 
                    'posts_per_page'      => 4, 
                    'cat'                 => 4, 
                    'no_found_rows'       => true, 
                    'cache_results'       => false 
                );
                $query_2 = new WP_Query( $args_2 );
                update_post_thumbnail_cache( $query );

                if ( $query_2->have_posts() ) { 
                    $i_cont_2 = 0;
                    $count = 0;

                    while ( $query_2->have_posts() ) { 

                        $query_2->the_post();
                        if ( $i_cont_2 == 0 ) { 
                            $post_class = ' ws-post-first'; 
                        } else { 
                            $post_class = ' ws-post-sec'; 
                        }

                        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
                            $has_class =  ''; 
                        } else { 
                            $has_class =  ' no-thumb'; 
                        }

                        if( $count % 3 == 1 ) { 
                            $code .= '<div class="row">'; 
                        }

                        $code .= '<div class="post'.$post_class.$has_class.'" role="article" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
                                    <div class="ws-meta">
                                        <h3 itemprop="name" class="entry-title">
                                            <a itemprop="url" href="<' . get_permalink( $post->ID ) . ' rel="bookmark">' . the_title() . '</a>
                                        </h3>
                                    </div>
                                </div>';

                        if( $count % 3 == 0 ) { 
                            $code .= "</div>\n"; 
                        }

                        if ( $count % 3 != 1 ) { 
                            $code .= "</div>";
                        }

                        $count++;
                        $i_cont_2++; 
                    }
                    wp_reset_postdata(); 
                }

            $code .= '</div>
        </div>
    </div>';

    return $code;
}
```